# Kafka on Multiple Servers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, devops

I followed this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install Kafka + Zookeeper. It all works well, yet I am setting up Kafka + Zookeeper on 2 servers.

I have setup the `kafka/config/server.properties` to have:

- Server 1: `broker.id = 0`
- Server 1: `zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181,99.99.99.91:2181`
- Server 2: `broker.id = 1`
- Server 2: `zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181,99.99.99.92:2181`

**I am wondering the follwing:**

- When I publish a topic, does it go to both Instances, or just the server it's loaded on?
- In order to use multiple servers like this, would I be required to use something like HAProxy with say 3 servers?
- Is there anything important I am missing with using 3 servers?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very beginning, I would be assuming that the instance mentioned here refers to a Kafka server instance.

Question #1: Information for the new-created topics will be stored in Zookeeper and some key information will be loaded into all brokers' metadata cache buffer.

Question #2: No need to configure any kind of proxy servers for Kafka cluster. It's self managed to implement the fail-over and load-balancing.

Question #3: Assigning an unused id and data directory like what you did for those two brokers is enough.

At last but not least, due to the fact that ZAB requires a majority, it is best to use an odd number of machines as the zookeeper quorum.

Comment: Thanks! i understand the endpoint to Server 1, and it goes to 2 or 3 with Kafka/ZK. But if server 1 had an outage, then the endpoint for all Kafka/ZK would have a single point of failure, that's why I was wondering how people skirt around that, maybe a DNS heartbeat or something?

Comment: One of the brokers will be elected as a controller which is in charge of topic/partition management. If controller is crashed, Kafka initiates an automatic election for a new controller. Users do not have to worry about anything during this process.